# How to refer to a variable table that has no primary key?

Tags: sql, postgresql

It may be that this question is sooo basic that I’m unable to find an answer via googling it. I’m very new to SQL. Using PostgreSQL 9.6.5 and  pgAdmin4.

I have a table that contains a single row with many columns and associated values that is named `parameters`. This table has no primary key.
The table consists of variables that change frequently. I’d like to be able to refer these variables from other tables.

Currently, from these other tables, I’m referring to the parameter values by using a select statement but this method is very cumbersome:

```
CASE WHEN t1.somevalue BETWEEN 
        ((select par1 from dbmain.parameters)
         * (select par2 from dbmain.parameters))
        AND
        ((select par1 from dbmain.parameters)
         * (select par3 from dbmain.parameters))
     THEN 1
END
```

I would rather write something like this:

```
CASE WHEN t1.headwtr BETWEEN p.par1 * p.par2
                         AND p.par1 * p.par3
     THEN 1
END
```

joined somehow to `dbmain.parameters AS p`

But since the parameter table does not have a primary key and none of the fields contained in it have matching values in the other tables I don’t see a way to properly join it.
How would you do this? Is there a better approach to accessing a shared variable type table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join that table; just use a `CROSS JOIN`. Then your single element table will be joined to every row.

Answer (score 0):

Create a parameter table that has a primary key, and 2 other columns: a column that contains the parameter-name and a column that contains the parameter-value.